# How to assign specific sitemaps for specific crawler-bots in robots.txt?

Tags: sitemap, robots.txt, web-crawler

Since some crawlers don't like the sitemap versions made for Google, I made different sitemaps.

And there is an option to put

```
Sitemap: http://example.com/sitemap.xml
```

to robots.txt. But is it possible to put it kinda like this:

```
User-agent: *
Sitemap: http://example.com/sitemap.xml

User-agent: googlebot
Sitemap: http://example.com/sitemap-for-google.xml
```

I couldn't find any resource for this topic and robots.txt is not something I want to joke around with.

Comment: Just an idea: Serve different robots.txt based on the User-Agent using for example a PHP script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible in robots.txt. The `Sitemap:` value will be used by *all* supporting consumers.

[Sitemaps.org protocol](http://www.sitemaps.org/protocol.html#submit_robots):

> This directive is independent of the user-agent line, so it doesn't matter where you place it in your file.

[Mentioned alternatives](http://www.sitemaps.org/protocol.html#informing): submit the sitemaps to the search engines [via their website](http://www.sitemaps.org/protocol.html#submit_engine) or [via HTTP requests](http://www.sitemaps.org/protocol.html#submit_ping).