# Robots.txt blocking all pages except selected ones

Tags: robots.txt

```
User-agent: *
Sitemap: https://somedomain.com/sitemap.xml
Disallow: /
Allow: /sitemap.xml
Allow: /some-page
Allow: /some-other-page
```

After submitting sitemap manually via google webmaster tools, it says that it can't read the Allowed pages, because they are blocked by robots.txt.

How to modify robots.txt, to allow them to be indexed, but leaving the rest of portal pages non-indexed?

Comment: Did you change the robots.txt recently resp. is it a new robots.txt? If this robots.txt is hosted at `https://somedomain.com/robots.txt`, is the URL you want to allow `https://somedomain.com/some-page`?

Comment: Yes to all questions.

Answer (score 0):

It’s probably just a matter of time until Google recognizes the new/updated robots.txt.

You can "ask Google to more quickly crawl and index a new robots.txt file for your site" in the Google Webmaster Tools: [Submit your updated robots.txt to Google](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6078399?hl=en).

Side note: As [the `Sitemap` field does not belong to a single record](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24985668/1591669) (as the protocol [defines](http://www.sitemaps.org/protocol.html#submit_robots): "independent of the user-agent line"), you might want to structure your robots.txt like this:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
Allow: /sitemap.xml
Allow: /some-page
Allow: /some-other-page

Sitemap: https://somedomain.com/sitemap.xml
```